# Firefox And CSS Menu Animation

Tags: jquery, css, firefox

I have a slide-out push menu, in which I have the links animated to fade in and up using CSS. I am having two problems.

1. The biggest problem I am having is that the animation does not reload itself in Firefox. In all the other browsers, no matter how many times you open and close the menu, the links animate in. Firefox will only run the animation once on page load. (I am using a Mac, running the latest version of Firefox).
2. Both in Firefox and Safari the links do not smooth fade in, they animate up fine, but they seem to snap in the fading part. The JSFiddle I have below for some reason does not show this that well, but when running the full site in the browser it is very noticeable.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johnw7989/dbLu7nhe/) of the below:

```js
(function($) {

  $.slidebars = function(options) {

    // ----------------------
    // 001 - Default Settings

    var settings = $.extend({
      siteClose: true, // true or false - Enable closing of Slidebars by clicking on #sb-site.
      scrollLock: false, // true or false - Prevent scrolling of site when a Slidebar is open.
      disableOver: false, // integer or false - Hide Slidebars over a specific width.
      hideControlClasses: false // true or false - Hide controls at same width as disableOver.
    }, options);

    // -----------------------
    // 002 - Feature Detection

    var test = document.createElement('div').style, // Create element to test on.
      supportTransition = false, // Variable for testing transitions.
      supportTransform = false; // variable for testing transforms.

    // Test for CSS Transitions
    if (test.MozTransition === '' || test.WebkitTransition === '' || test.OTransition === '' || test.transition === '') supportTransition = true;

    // Test for CSS Transforms
    if (test.MozTransform === '' || test.WebkitTransform === '' || test.OTransform === '' || test.transform === '') supportTransform = true;

    // -----------------
    // 003 - User Agents

    var ua = navigator.userAgent, // Get user agent string.
      android = false, // Variable for storing android version.
      iOS = false; // Variable for storing iOS version.

    if (/Android/.test(ua)) { // Detect Android in user agent string.
      android = ua.substr(ua.indexOf('Android') + 8, 3); // Set version of Android.
    } else if (/(iPhone|iPod|iPad)/.test(ua)) { // Detect iOS in user agent string.
      iOS = ua.substr(ua.indexOf('OS ') + 3, 3).replace('_', '.'); // Set version of iOS.
    }

    if (android && android < 3 || iOS && iOS < 5) $('html').addClass('sb-static'); // Add helper class for older versions of Android & iOS.

    // -----------
    // 004 - Setup

    // Site container
    var $site = $('#sb-site, .sb-site-container'); // Cache the selector.

    // Left Slidebar 
    if ($('.sb-left').length) { // Check if the left Slidebar exists.
      var $left = $('.sb-left'), // Cache the selector.
        leftActive = false; // Used to check whether the left Slidebar is open or closed.
    }

    // Right Slidebar
    if ($('.sb-right').length) { // Check if the right Slidebar exists.
      var $right = $('.sb-right'), // Cache the selector.
        rightActive = false; // Used to check whether the right Slidebar is open or closed.
    }

    var init = false, // Initialisation variable.
      windowWidth = $(window).width(), // Get width of window.
      $controls = $('.sb-toggle-left, .sb-toggle-right, .sb-open-left, .sb-open-right, .sb-close'), // Cache the control classes.
      $slide = $('.sb-slide'); // Cache users elements to animate.

    // Initailise Slidebars
    function initialise() {
      if (!settings.disableOver || (typeof settings.disableOver === 'number' && settings.disableOver >= windowWidth)) { // False or larger than window size. 
        init = true; // true enabled Slidebars to open.
        $('html').addClass('sb-init'); // Add helper class.
        if (settings.hideControlClasses) $controls.removeClass('sb-hide'); // Remove class just incase Slidebars was originally disabled.
        css(); // Set required inline styles.
      } else if (typeof settings.disableOver === 'number' && settings.disableOver < windowWidth) { // Less than window size.
        init = false; // false stop Slidebars from opening.
        $('html').removeClass('sb-init'); // Remove helper class.
        if (settings.hideControlClasses) $controls.addClass('sb-hide'); // Hide controls
        $site.css('minHeight', ''); // Remove minimum height.
        if (leftActive || rightActive) close(); // Close Slidebars if open.
      }
    }
    initialise();

    // Inline CSS
    function css() {
      // Set minimum height.
      $site.css('minHeight', ''); // Reset minimum height.
      $site.css('minHeight', $('html').height() + 'px'); // Set minimum height of the site to the minimum height of the html.

      // Custom Slidebar widths.
      if ($left && $left.hasClass('sb-width-custom')) $left.css('width', $left.attr('data-sb-width')); // Set user custom width.
      if ($right && $right.hasClass('sb-width-custom')) $right.css('width', $right.attr('data-sb-width')); // Set user custom width.

      // Set off-canvas margins for Slidebars with push and overlay animations.
      if ($left && ($left.hasClass('sb-style-push') || $left.hasClass('sb-style-overlay'))) $left.css('marginLeft', '-' + $left.css('width'));
      if ($right && ($right.hasClass('sb-style-push') || $right.hasClass('sb-style-overlay'))) $right.css('marginRight', '-' + $right.css('width'));

      // Site scroll locking.
      if (settings.scrollLock) $('html').addClass('sb-scroll-lock');
    }

    // Resize Functions
    $(window).resize(function() {
      var resizedWindowWidth = $(window).width(); // Get resized window width.
      if (windowWidth !== resizedWindowWidth) { // Slidebars is running and window was actually resized.
        windowWidth = resizedWindowWidth; // Set the new window width.
        initialise(); // Call initalise to see if Slidebars should still be running.
        if (leftActive) open('left'); // If left Slidebar is open, calling open will ensure it is the correct size.
        if (rightActive) open('right'); // If right Slidebar is open, calling open will ensure it is the correct size.
      }
    });
    // I may include a height check along side a width check here in future.

    // ---------------
    // 005 - Animation

    var animation; // Animation type.

    // Set animation type.
    if (supportTransition && supportTransform) { // Browser supports css transitions and transforms.
      animation = 'translate'; // Translate for browsers that support it.
      if (android && android < 4.4) animation = 'side'; // Android supports both, but can't translate any fixed positions, so use left instead.
    } else {
      animation = 'jQuery'; // Browsers that don't support css transitions and transitions.
    }

    // Animate mixin.
    function animate(object, amount, side) {
      // Choose selectors depending on animation style.
      var selector;

      if (object.hasClass('sb-style-push')) {
        selector = $site.add(object).add($slide); // Push - Animate site, Slidebar and user elements.
      } else if (object.hasClass('sb-style-overlay')) {
        selector = object; // Overlay - Animate Slidebar only.
      } else {
        selector = $site.add($slide); // Reveal - Animate site and user elements.
      }

      // Apply animation
      if (animation === 'translate') {
        selector.css('transform', 'translate(' + amount + ')'); // Apply the animation.

      } else if (animation === 'side') {
        if (amount[0] === '-') amount = amount.substr(1); // Remove the '-' from the passed amount for side animations.
        if (amount !== '0px') selector.css(side, '0px'); // Add a 0 value so css transition works.
        setTimeout(function() { // Set a timeout to allow the 0 value to be applied above.
          selector.css(side, amount); // Apply the animation.
        }, 1);

      } else if (animation === 'jQuery') {
        if (amount[0] === '-') amount = amount.substr(1); // Remove the '-' from the passed amount for jQuery animations.
        var properties = {};
        properties[side] = amount;
        selector.stop().animate(properties, 400); // Stop any current jQuery animation before starting another.
      }

      // If closed, remove the inline styling on completion of the animation.
      setTimeout(function() {
        if (amount === '0px') {
          selector.removeAttr('style');
          css();
        }
      }, 400);
    }

    // ----------------
    // 006 - Operations

    // Open a Slidebar
    function open(side) {
      // Check to see if opposite Slidebar is open.
      if (side === 'left' && $left && rightActive || side === 'right' && $right && leftActive) { // It's open, close it, then continue.
        close();
        setTimeout(proceed, 400);
      } else { // Its not open, continue.
        proceed();
      }

      // Open
      function proceed() {
        if (init && side === 'left' && $left) { // Slidebars is initiated, left is in use and called to open.
          $('html').addClass('sb-active sb-active-left'); // Add active classes.
          $left.addClass('sb-active');
          animate($left, $left.css('width'), 'left'); // Animation
          setTimeout(function() {
            leftActive = true;
          }, 400); // Set active variables.
        } else if (init && side === 'right' && $right) { // Slidebars is initiated, right is in use and called to open.
          $('html').addClass('sb-active sb-active-right'); // Add active classes.
          $right.addClass('sb-active');
          animate($right, '-' + $right.css('width'), 'right'); // Animation
          setTimeout(function() {
            rightActive = true;
          }, 400); // Set active variables.
        }
      }
    }

    // Close either Slidebar
    function close(link) {
      if (leftActive || rightActive) { // If a Slidebar is open.
        if (leftActive) {
          animate($left, '0px', 'left'); // Animation
          leftActive = false;
        }
        if (rightActive) {
          animate($right, '0px', 'right'); // Animation
          rightActive = false;
        }

        setTimeout(function() { // Wait for closing animation to finish.
          $('html').removeClass('sb-active sb-active-left sb-active-right'); // Remove active classes.
          if ($left) $left.removeClass('sb-active');
          if ($right) $right.removeClass('sb-active');
          if (typeof link !== 'undefined') window.location = link; // If a link has been passed to the function, go to it.
        }, 400);
      }
    }

    // Toggle either Slidebar
    function toggle(side) {
      if (side === 'left' && $left) { // If left Slidebar is called and in use.
        if (!leftActive) {
          open('left'); // Slidebar is closed, open it.
        } else {
          close(); // Slidebar is open, close it.
        }
      }
      if (side === 'right' && $right) { // If right Slidebar is called and in use.
        if (!rightActive) {
          open('right'); // Slidebar is closed, open it.
        } else {
          close(); // Slidebar is open, close it.
        }
      }
    }

    // ---------
    // 007 - API

    this.slidebars = {
      open: open, // Maps user variable name to the open method.
      close: close, // Maps user variable name to the close method.
      toggle: toggle, // Maps user variable name to the toggle method.
      init: function() { // Returns true or false whether Slidebars are running or not.
        return init; // Returns true or false whether Slidebars are running.
      },
      active: function(side) { // Returns true or false whether Slidebar is open or closed.
        if (side === 'left' && $left) return leftActive;
        if (side === 'right' && $right) return rightActive;
      },
      destroy: function(side) { // Removes the Slidebar from the DOM.
        if (side === 'left' && $left) {
          if (leftActive) close(); // Close if its open.
          setTimeout(function() {
            $left.remove(); // Remove it.
            $left = false; // Set variable to false so it cannot be opened again.
          }, 400);
        }
        if (side === 'right' && $right) {
          if (rightActive) close(); // Close if its open.
          setTimeout(function() {
            $right.remove(); // Remove it.
            $right = false; // Set variable to false so it cannot be opened again.
          }, 400);
        }
      }
    };

    // ----------------
    // 008 - User Input

    function eventHandler(event, selector) {
      event.stopPropagation(); // Stop event bubbling.
      event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default behaviour
      if (event.type === 'touchend') selector.off('click'); // If event type was touch turn off clicks to prevent phantom clicks.
    }

    // Toggle left Slidebar
    $('.sb-toggle-left').on('touchend click', function(event) {
      eventHandler(event, $(this)); // Handle the event.
      toggle('left'); // Toggle the left Slidbar.
    });

    // Toggle right Slidebar
    $('.sb-toggle-right').on('touchend click', function(event) {
      eventHandler(event, $(this)); // Handle the event.
      toggle('right'); // Toggle the right Slidbar.
    });

    // Open left Slidebar
    $('.sb-open-left').on('touchend click', function(event) {
      eventHandler(event, $(this)); // Handle the event.
      open('left'); // Open the left Slidebar.
    });

    // Open right Slidebar
    $('.sb-open-right').on('touchend click', function(event) {
      eventHandler(event, $(this)); // Handle the event.
      open('right'); // Open the right Slidebar.
    });

    // Close a Slidebar
    $('.sb-close').on('touchend click', function(event) {
      eventHandler(event, $(this)); // Handle the event.
      var link;

      // Close Slidebar via link
      if ($(this).parents('.sb-slidebar')) {
        if ($(this).is('a')) {
          link = $(this).attr('href');
        } else if ($(this).children('a')) {
          link = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
        }
      }

      close(link); // Close Slidebar and pass link.
    });

    // Close Slidebar via site
    $site.on('touchend click', function(event) {
      if (settings.siteClose && (leftActive || rightActive)) { // If settings permit closing by site and left or right Slidebar is open.
        eventHandler(event, $(this)); // Handle the event.
        close(); // Close it.
      }
    });

  }; // End Slidebars function.

})(jQuery);
```

```css
html,
body,
#sb-site,
.sb-site-container,
.sb-slidebar {
  /* Set box model to prevent any user added margins or paddings from altering the widths or heights. */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* Stops horizontal scrolling. */
}
html {
  height: 100%;
  /* Site is as tall as device. */
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  /* Required for static Slidebars to function properly. */
}
html.sb-scroll-lock.sb-active:not(.sb-static) {
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Prevent site from scrolling when a Slidebar is open, except when static Slidebars are only available. */
}
/* ----------
 * 002 - Site
 */

#sb-site,
.sb-site-container {
  /* You may now use class .sb-site-container instead of #sb-site and use your own id. However please make sure you don't set any of the following styles any differently on your id. */
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  /* Site sits above Slidebars */
  background-color: #ffffff;
  /* Default background colour, overwrite this with your own css. I suggest moving your html or body background styling here. Making this transparent will allow the Slidebars beneath to be visible. */
}
/* ---------------
 * 003 - Slidebars
 */

.sb-slidebar {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* Enable vertical scrolling on Slidebars when needed. */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  /* Slidebars sit behind sb-site. */
  display: none;
  /* Initially hide the Slidebars. Changed from visibility to display to allow -webkit-overflow-scrolling. */
  background-color: #222222;
  /* Default Slidebars background colour, overwrite this with your own css. */
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px);
  /* Fixes issues with translated and z-indexed elements on iOS 7. */
}
.sb-left {
  left: 0;
  /* Set Slidebar to the left. */
}
.sb-right {
  right: 0;
  /* Set Slidebar to the right. */
}
html.sb-static .sb-slidebar,
.sb-slidebar.sb-static {
  position: absolute;
  /* Makes Slidebars scroll naturally with the site, and unfixes them for Android Browser < 3 and iOS < 5. */
}
.sb-slidebar.sb-active {
  display: block;
  /* Makes Slidebars visibile when open. Changed from visibility to display to allow -webkit-overflow-scrolling. */
}
.sb-style-overlay {
  z-index: 9999;
  /* Set z-index high to ensure it overlays any other site elements. */
}
.sb-momentum-scrolling {
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  /* Adds native momentum scrolling for iOS & Android devices. */
}
/* Slidebar widths for browsers/devices that don't support media queries. */

.sb-slidebar {
  width: 30%;
}
.sb-width-thin {
  width: 15%;
}
.sb-width-wide {
  width: 45%;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  /* Slidebar widths on extra small screens. */
  .sb-slidebar {
    width: 70%;
  }
  .sb-width-thin {
    width: 55%;
  }
  .sb-width-wide {
    width: 85%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 481px) {
  /* Slidebar widths on small screens. */
  .sb-slidebar {
    width: 55%;
  }
  .sb-width-thin {
    width: 40%;
  }
  .sb-width-wide {
    width: 70%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* Slidebar widths on medium screens. */
  .sb-slidebar {
    width: 40%;
  }
  .sb-width-thin {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .sb-width-wide {
    width: 55%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  /* Slidebar widths on large screens. */
  .sb-slidebar {
    width: 30%;
  }
  .sb-width-thin {
    width: 15%;
  }
  .sb-width-wide {
    width: 45%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  /* Slidebar widths on extra large screens. */
  .sb-slidebar {
    width: 20%;
  }
  .sb-width-thin {
    width: 5%;
  }
  .sb-width-wide {
    width: 35%;
  }
}
/* ---------------
 * 004 - Animation
 */

.sb-slide,
#sb-site,
.sb-site-container,
.sb-slidebar {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 400ms ease;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 400ms ease;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 400ms ease;
  transition: transform 400ms ease;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, left, right;
  /* Add left/right for Android < 4.4. */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Prevents flickering. This is non essential, and you may remove it if your having problems with fixed background images in Chrome. */
}
/* --------------------
 * 005 - Helper Classes
 */

.sb-hide {
  display: none;
  /* Optionally applied to control classes when Slidebars is disabled over a certain width. */
}
/* --------------------
 * 004 - Slidebar Menus
 */

/* Main Menu */

.sb-menu {
  /* Apply to <ul> or <ol>. */
  padding-top: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.sb-menu li {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  border-top: 0px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03);
  /* Will lighten any background colour you set. */
  border-bottom: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
  /* Will darken any background colour you set. */
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  word-spacing: 0px;
}
.sb-toggle-right {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 1.5em;
}
.sb-menu li a {
  width: 100%;
  /* Makes links full width. */
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1.5em;
  /* Creates an even padding the same size as your font. */
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 5.8em;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* CALL TO ANIMATE */
}
.sb-menu > li:nth-child(1) {
  border-top: none;
  /* Removes top border from first list item.. */
  margin-top: -40px;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
  text-align: center !important;
}
.sb-menu > li:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation: fadeInUpBig 1s forwards;
  animation: fadeInUpBig 1s forwards;
}
.sb-menu > li:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation: fadeInUpBig 1.1s;
  animation: fadeInUpBig 1.1s;
}
.sb-menu > li:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation: fadeInUpBig 1.2s forwards;
  animation: fadeInUpBig 1.2s forwards;
}
.sb-menu > li:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation: fadeInUpBig 1.3s forwards;
  animation: fadeInUpBig 1.3s forwards;
}
.sb-menu > li:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-animation: fadeInUpBig 1.4s forwards;
  animation: fadeInUpBig 1.4s forwards;
}
.sb-menu > li:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-animation: fadeInUpBig 1.5s forwards;
  animation: fadeInUpBig 1.5s forwards;
}
.sb-menu > li:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-animation: fadeInUpBig 1.6s forwards;
  animation: fadeInUpBig 1.6s forwards;
}
.sb-menu > li:nth-child(9) {
  -webkit-animation: fadeInUpBig 1.7s forwards;
  animation: fadeInUpBig 1.7s forwards;
}
/* ANIMATION CSS */

Copyright (c) 2014 Daniel Eden */ .animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.animated.infinite {
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.animated.hinge {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 53%, 80%, 100% {
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  40%,
  43% {
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -4px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -4px, 0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUpBig {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 300px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 300px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeInUpBig {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 300px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 300px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}
.fadeInUpBig {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUpBig;
  animation-name: fadeInUpBig;
}
```

```html
<div id="sb-site">
  <ul>
    <li class="sb-toggle-right">Toggle right Slidebar</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="sb-slidebar sb-right">
  <!-- Lists in Slidebars -->
  <ul class="sb-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Navigation</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Sample 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Sample 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Sample 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Sample 4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Sample 5</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Sample 6</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Sample 7</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  (function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.slidebars();
    });
  })(jQuery);
</script>

<!-- Slidebars -->
```

Comment: @misterManSam Oh sorry, Didn't understand what it meant by that (first time using a JSFiddle), now I know.